# Core data entity manager

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I want to write class for manage all entity that i have in my application.
there is my code fore managerClass for one custom entity, but I have a problem to set manageObject type in this context.

```
public func clearEntityContex() {

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Shop> = Shop.fetchRequest()

    if  let fetchResult = try? self.stack.mainQueueContext.fetch(fetchRequest){
      for user : Shop in fetchResult {
        self.stack.mainQueueContext.delete(user as Shop)
      }
      do {
        try stack.mainQueueContext.save()
      }
      catch {
        debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
      }
    }
  }

  //MARK: _fetch Contex
  public func fetchsShopEntity() -> [Shop]? {

    var shops : [Shop]?

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Shop> = Shop.fetchRequest()

    do {
      let fetchResult =
        try self.stack.mainQueueContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

      if fetchResult.count > 0 {

        shops = fetchResult
      }
    }
    catch {
      fatalError("Failed to fetch Account: \(error)")
    }

    return shops
  }

  //MARK: _save entity
  public func saveEntityInModel(entityItem : Shop){

    if  let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Shop", in: self.stack.mainQueueContext) {

      if let contex = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: self.stack.mainQueueContext) as? Shop {

        contex.packID = entityItem.packID
        contex.packName = entityItem.packName
        contex.packImage = entityItem.packImage
        contex.priceDolar = entityItem.priceDolar
        contex.packDescription = entityItem.packDescription

        do {
          try stack.mainQueueContext.save()
        }
        catch {
          debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

for example i want to write method that can clear any entityContext. but i cant pass manageObject to this method.

```
public func clearEntityContex(entityObject: NSManagedObject) {

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = entityObject.fetchRequest()

    if  let fetchResult = try? self.stack.mainQueueContext.fetch(fetchRequest){
      for entity  in fetchResult {
        self.stack.mainQueueContext.delete(entity as entityObject)
      }
      do {
        try stack.mainQueueContext.save()
      }
      catch {
        debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
      }
    }
  }
```

how can solve pass NSManagedObject to this method?
thanks for all reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more generic implementation that we use in our projects.

```
import CoreData

class ACSwiftCoreData: ACCoreDataPlugin {

let managedObjectModelName: String
let databasePath: URL

init(managedObjectModelName: String, databasePath: URL) {
    self.managedObjectModelName = managedObjectModelName
    self.databasePath = databasePath
}

// MARK: Managed Object Contexts

private var sharedContext: NSManagedObjectContext?

func getSharedManagedObjectContext() throws -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    if let sharedContext = self.sharedContext {
        return sharedContext
    }

    let context = try self.createManagedObjectContext()
    self.sharedContext = context
    return context
}

func createManagedObjectContext() throws -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    let storeCoordinator = try self.getPersistentStoreCoordinator()

    let managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = storeCoordinator
    managedObjectContext.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy(merge: NSMergePolicyType.mergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicyType)

    return managedObjectContext
}

// MARK: Creating Entities

func createEntityInSharedContext<EntityType>(_ entityName: String) throws -> EntityType {
    let context = try self.getSharedManagedObjectContext()
    return try self.createEntity(entityName, context: context)
}

func createEntity<EntityType>(_ entityName: String, context: NSManagedObjectContext) throws -> EntityType {
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: entityName, into: context)

    guard let expectedEntity = entity as? EntityType else {
        throw self.errorWithMessage("ACSwiftCoreData: Entity for name \(entityName) does not match class \(EntityType.self).")
    }

    return expectedEntity
}

// MARK: Saving Entity

func saveEntity(_ entity: NSManagedObject) throws {
    guard let context = entity.managedObjectContext else {
        throw errorWithMessage("ACSwiftCoreData: Cannot save Entity. ManagedObjectContext is missing.")
    }

    if context.hasChanges {
        try context.save()
    }
}

// MARK: Delete Entity

func deleteEntity(_ entity: NSManagedObject) throws {
    guard let context = entity.managedObjectContext else {
        throw errorWithMessage("ACSwiftCoreData: Cannot delete Entity. ManagedObjectContext is missing.")
    }

    context.delete(entity)
    try context.save()
}

// MARK: Fetch Requests

func fetchEntitiesInSharedContext<EntityType: AnyObject>(_ entityName: String, predicate: NSPredicate?) -> [EntityType] {
    guard let context = try? self.getSharedManagedObjectContext() else {
        return [EntityType]()
    }

    return self .fetchEntities(entityName, context: context, predicate: predicate)
}

func fetchEntities<EntityType: AnyObject>(_ entityName: String, context: NSManagedObjectContext, predicate: NSPredicate?) -> [EntityType] {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entityName)
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    let results = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest)

    guard let resultEntitys = results as? [EntityType] else {
        return [EntityType]()
    }

    return resultEntitys
}

// MARK: Technical Details

private var storeCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator?

private func getPersistentStoreCoordinator() throws -> NSPersistentStoreCoordinator {
    if let storeCoordinator = self.storeCoordinator {
        return storeCoordinator
    }

    let model = try self.getManagedObjectModel()

    let storeCoordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: model)

    var options = [AnyHashable: Any]()
    options[NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption] = true
    options[NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption] = true

    try storeCoordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: self.databasePath, options: options)

    self.storeCoordinator = storeCoordinator
    return storeCoordinator
}

private var objectModel: NSManagedObjectModel?

private func getManagedObjectModel() throws -> NSManagedObjectModel {
    if let objectModel = self.objectModel {
        return objectModel
    }

    let momName = self.managedObjectModelName
    guard let modelUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: momName, withExtension:"momd") else {
        throw self.errorWithMessage("ACSwiftCoreData: DataModel Url could not be created.")
    }

    guard let objectModel = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelUrl) else {
        throw self.errorWithMessage("ACSwiftCoreData: DataModel could not be loaded.")
    }

    self.objectModel = objectModel
    return objectModel
}

// MARK: Error handling

private func errorWithMessage(_ message: String) -> NSError {
    let userInfo = [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: message]
    let error = NSError(domain: "com.appcron.accomponents", code: 0, userInfo: userInfo)
    return error
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In some project that I made and when I used CoreData, I usually create a Singleton with function to fetch, save and delete a CoreData object.
This is my CoreDataController:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
import UIKit

final class CoreDataController {

    static let sharedInstances = CoreDataController()
    private var context: NSManagedObjectContext

    private init(){
       let application = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
       self.context = application.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }

func loadAll() {
    print("Fetch from CoreData")

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<YourEntity> = YourEntity.fetchRequest()

    do {
        let entityArray = try self.context.fetch(fetchRequest)

        guard entityArray.count > 0 else {
            print("There aren't element in CoreData "); return}

    } catch let error {
        print("FetchRequest error")
        print(" Print error: \n \(error) \n")
    }
}

func save(entityToSave: String, item: String){

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: entityToSave, in: self.context)

    let newItem = YourEntity(entity: entity!, insertInto: self.context)
    newItem.name = item
    do {
        try self.context.save()
    } catch let error {
        print("Problem with \(newItem)")
        print("  Print error: \n \(error) \n")
    }

    print("Element \(newItem) saved in CoreData")


}

func loadFromName(entityName:String, name: String) -> Any {

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entityName)
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "yourEntityAttribute = %@", yourEntityAttribute)

    request.predicate = predicate

    let items = self.loadFromFetchRequest(request: request)

    return items[0]
}



private func loadFromFetchRequest(request: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>) -> [Any] {
    var array = [Any]()
    do {
        array = try self.context.fetch(request)

        guard array.count > 0 else {print("There aren't element in CoreData"); return []}

        for item in array {
            print("Item: \(item)")
        }

    } catch let error {
        print("FetchRequest Error")
        print("  Print Error: \n \(error) \n")
    }

    return array
}


func delete(entityName: String, name: String) {
    let item = self.loadFromName(entityName: entityName, name: name)

    self.context.delete(item as! NSManagedObject)

    do {
        try self.context.save()
    } catch let error {
        print("Deleting problem")
        print("Print Error: \n \(error) \n")
    }
}


func loadData(entity: String) -> [YourEntity] {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entity)
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    var data = [YourEntity]()

    do {
        data = try self.context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [YourEntity]

    } catch let error {
        print("Print Error: \n \(error) \n")
    }

    return data
   }

}
```

When you have to call, just write:

```
CoreDataController.sharedInstances.save(entityToSave: "Profile", item: textfield.text!)
```

or other functions!!!
I hope this is useful for you.

For use this Class with every Entity you can write like that:

```
 let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: entityToSave, in: self.context)
    let newItem: Any

    switch entityToSave {

    case "YourEntity":
        newItem = YourEntity(entity: entity!, insertInto: self.context)
        (newItem as! YourEntity).entityAttribute = firstItem
        (newItem as! YourEntity).entityAttribute = secondItem

    case "YourEntity2":
        newItem = YourEntity2(entity: entity!, insertInto: self.context)
        (newItem as! YourEntity2).entityAttribute = firstItem
        (newItem as! YourEntity2).entityAttribute = secondItem

    case "YourEntity3":
        newItem = YourEntity3(entity: entity!, insertInto: self.context)
        (newItem as! YourEntity3).entityAttribute = firstItem
        (newItem as! YourEntity3).entityAttribute = secondItem

    case "YourEntity4":
        newItem = YourEntity4(entity: entity!, insertInto: self.context)
        (newItem as! YourEntity4).entityAttribute = firstItem
        (newItem as! YourEntity4).entityAttribute = secondItem
    default:

        fatalError("Error in entityToSave function")
    }

    do {
        try self.context.save()
    } catch let error {
        print("Problem to save \(newItem)")
        print("Print Error: \n \(error) \n")
    }

    print("Element \(newItem) saved correctly")


}
```

Comment: thanks for reply , I have something like that, but i have one class for managed all entity. in your case i should add one entity instead YourEntity.

Comment: when i have five entity i should repeat this class for all five entity.

Comment: That was just an example. You can pass your entity by argument of function